# how can i do query biulder with (AND) for 3 or more parameters

Tags: php, laravel

im did a query for brand of car and the model but when i did added a
query to price range (whereBetwen) its not working

```php
public function indexBrowse(Request $request)
{
    $brand=$request->get('searchbrand');
    $model=$request->get('searchmodel');
    $searchtype=$request->get('searchtype');
    $from=$request->get('pricefrom');
    $to=$request->get('priecto');
    
    $cars=car::where('brand', 'like', '%'.$brand.'%')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($model) {
            $query->where('model','like','%'.$model.'%');
        })->where(function ($query2) use ($from,$to) {
            $query2->car::whereBetween('price',['%'.$from.'%','%'.$to.'%']);
        })->get();
        
    dd($cars);
    $success = 'Results Car';
    return view('cars.index', compact('cars', 'success'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if you want to perform all these where with and condition.

```
car::where('brand', 'like', '%'.$brand.'%')
    ->where('model','like','%'.$model.'%')
    ->whereBetween('price'['%'.$from.'%','%'.$to.'%'])->get();
```

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using?